# controls PictureBox question

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this Enum

```
public  enum Icon
{
    Question    = 1,
    Hand        = 2,
    Exclamation = 3,
    None        = 4
}
```

i have 4 PictureBox on my Form named

```
P1 , P2 , P3 and P4
```

if i have `Icon G`

how i can show any PictureBox like this:

Instead of `P2.visible = true`  i'll write   `G.Hand = True`

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have 4 PictureBox controls if you only have 1 icon? Why wouldn't you put the picture you want in each PictureBox control? But really what I think you need is 1 PictureBox control and 4 icons.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no need for four `PictureBox` controls, you just need to have one and select an image base on your enum like the following:

```
// Assuming you have a dictionary of icons pathes
Dictionary<Icon,string> icons = new Dictionary<Icon,string>();

icons[Icon.Question] = "..\imgQuestion.png" \\ path of question image";
icons[Icon.Hand] =
icons[Icon.Exclamation] =

pictureBoxControl.Image = icons[G.Hand];
```

Good luck!